Scrolling Line Chart CO2 Emissions
I would like to make a scrolling line chart like this, using Chart.js:

I have csv file called "annual_co_emissions_by_region" that has numerous countries listed as entities, I would like each of them to be a new line. I would like the scrolling time line to be from 1750 -2022. I would like the line chart to be similar to the fancy picture attached but more basic.


I am new to programming so i've tried various ways in VS Code. I need a simplified explanation of what goes into the HTML with headers included, what goes into CSS and what goes into .js. Thank you in advance.

Please show us what you have tried. I'm afraid SO isn't a tutorial or code-writing service - but we are very happy to help you with debugging code you have written.

Oh, yes, thank you for letting me know. I will post what I've already tried in the post.
